# lastpass cli generate with pronounceable password

Tags: lastpass

I'm using the lastpass cli to update passwords used in an automation process. I would like these passwords to be pronounceable.  Is there an arguments flag that can do this?

```
$ lpass generate 
Usage: lpass generate [--sync=auto|now|no] [--clip, -c] [--username=USERNAME] [--url=URL] [--no-symbols] {NAME|UNIQUEID} LENGTH
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? The whole point of using LastPass is that your passwords are handled for you by LastPass. It doesn't matter if the passwords are 'difficult to pronounce', as you're not supposed to remember them.

Comment: In this case lastpass will generate random passwords given to users in a training exercise.  We want them to be rotated for each session, but also want them to be easy for users to remember during their session as the users will not have lastpass accounts.